# Pug - generating Select and Options

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am new to Pug and I am trying to generate a Select set of Options like this:

```
select
each variable in variables
option(value=variable.id) #{variable.var_name}
```

However the result I get, in the rendered page, is an empty select input followed by the list of options as text

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Indents the code https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

```
select
  each variable in variables
    option(value=variable.id) #{variable.var_name}
```

Comment: sorry it was actually just an example the name I used is different. The problem was indeed the indentation